# Let F denote the set of all functions from {1,2,3} to {1,2,3,4,5}, find the following:...?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I guess it would make more sense if I understood what ' set of all functions from {1,2,3} to {1,2,3,4,5} ' means and know how many functions there actually are.

I need help with the following 3 questions, which I don't have a solution to, b/c I still have trouble with understanding the question.

a) Find and simply the number of functions $f∈F$ so that $f(1)=4$.

b) Find and simply the number of one-to-one functions $f∈F$ so that $f(1)\ge4$.

c) Find and simply the number of functions $f∈F$ so that $f(1)\neq f(2)$.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: A function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is any set $f$ of ordered pairs $\langle m,n\rangle$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $m\in\{1,2,3\}$,
- $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and
- for each $m\in\{1,2,3\}$ there is exactly one $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $\langle m,n\rangle\in f$. For convenience we normally write $f(m)=n$ to mean that $\langle m,n\rangle\in f$.

The first two conditions make $f$ a relation from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$; the last is what makes this relation a function. Here are two examples of functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$:

$$f=\{\langle 1,4\rangle,\langle 2,4\rangle,\langle 3,4\rangle\}\;,$$

and

$$g=\{\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 3,5\rangle\}\;.$$

The first is the constant function such that $f(m)=4$ for each $m\in\{1,2,3\}$. The second could be described in what is probably more familiar notation like this:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
g(1)&=1\\
g(2)&=3\\
g(3)&=5\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

To construct a function $h$ from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, you have to specify a value for $h(1)$, a value for $h(2)$, and a value for $h(3)$. For example, you could decide that $h(1)$ will be $3$, $h(2)$ will be $5$, and $h(3)$ will be $3$; this would make $h$ the function

$$h=\{\langle 1,3\rangle,\langle 2,5\rangle,\langle 3,3\rangle\}\;.$$

Each of these values $h(1),h(2)$, and $h(3)$ can be any member of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so you’re making a $5$-way choice $3$ times; this can be done in $5^3=125$ different ways.

- For the first question, notice that $f(1)=4$ has already been specified, so you have only to choose $f(2)$ and $f(3)$.
- For the second, notice that $f(1)$ is required to be $4$ or $5$, so there are $2$ choices for $f(1)$. Once $f(1)$ has been decided, how many choices are there for $f(2)$ if the function is required to be one-to-one? And once $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ have both been decided, how many choices remain for $f(3)$, again bearing in mind that $f$ is supposed to be one-to-one?
- For the third, how many choices are there for $f(1)$? Once you’ve chosen $f(1)$, how many are there for $f(2)$? And once you’ve chosen those, how many are there for $f(3)$? Combine those answers properly, and you’ll have the result.

Comment: For a) my answer is 5^2, b/c we are making 5 choices 2 times

Comment: For b) my answer is : 2 choices for f(1), 4 choices for f(2), 5 choices for f(3)
thus the final answer is 2*4*5 = 40 one-to-one functions

Comment: I am not sure about c) thought wouldn't the answer be the same as in a) 5^2?

Comment: @00111000: Your answer for (a) is correct. For (b) you started out okay but went astray at the end: there are $2$ choices for $f(1)$, and there are then $4$ choices for $f(2)$, since you can’t repeat a selection if you want to get a one-to-one function. At that point, though, you’ve used up two of the five members of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, so you have only $3$ choices available for $f(3)$: you can’t use $f(1)$ or $f(2)$ again and still have a one-to-one function. \\ No, the answer to (c) is definitely not the same as the answer to (a). Every function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ either ...

Comment: ... has $f(1)=4$, in which case it’s one that we count in (a), or has $f(1)\ne 4$, in which case it’s one that we count in (c). No function is in both of these categories, so the number counted in (a) and the number counted in (c) must add up to the total number, which is $5^3$.

Comment: Hey, I just realized that I have written c) incorrectly, I have updated the question.

Comment: @00111000: I just revised the answer to match the corrected question.

Comment: Hope I am not annoying you, but I said that there are 5 choices for f(1) then there are 4 choices for f(2), and there are 5 choices for f(3). Is my answer correct or should there be 3 choices for f(3)?

Comment: @00111000: Your answer is correct. Another way to reason it out is to notice there are $5^2$ functions such that $f(1)=f(2)$, since you’re basically just picking $f(1)$ and $f(3)$ arbitrarily, and hence $5^3-5^2=5^2\cdot 4$ such that $f(1)\ne f(2)$.